# How to filter Excel column?

Tags: path

I am looking for a solution in python for my data which is in an excel file that contains different statements and numbers. I want to filter out the rows on the base of column values.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read.excel("Data.xlsx")
df[df.Numbers.apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]
df.to_excel("Data1.xlsx")
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to perform the filtering, using pandas' string tools and boolean masks.  I did each step separately (easier to test, and easier to understand in the future).

```
# remove CAS and Cascade
mask = (df['Evaluations'].str.startswith('CAS') | 
        df['Evaluations'].str.contains('CASCADE'))
df = df[~mask]

# remove Numbers starting with 21 or 99
mask = (df['Numbers'].astype(str).str.startswith('21') | 
        df['Numbers'].astype(str).str.startswith('99'))
df = df[~mask]

# remove letter as 2th character (1 => zero-based indexing)
mask = df['Numbers'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[1].isalpha())
df = df[~mask]

# write to file
with open('Data1.xlsx', 'wb') as handle:
    df.to_excel(handle)
    
print(df)

                      Evaluations   Numbers
2  Nastolgic behaviours of people  75903324
3                    google drive  76308764
6          Tesla's new inventions  83492836
7                   Electric cars  78363522
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1- If in the column named Evaluations, its content starts with "OBS" or has the word "Obsolete" in it then remove these rows

```
(^OBS|Obsolete)
```

> 2- If the column value in the Numbers column start with digits "99" or "51" then remove these rows

```
^(99|51)
```

> 3- If the 5th digit in the Numbers column is an alphabetic character then also remove these rows

```
^\d{4}\w
```

These are the Regexes that will help match these conditions.

Comment: Thank you, @Hass But how I will use these commands at once. would you write a one-liner code or something to explain it better? I am new to python